# Keras-TF model.predict() gave me wrong result

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I just trained my CNN model which has the layer details below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(100, (3, 3), input_shape=(100, 100, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(120, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(140, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My model has about **95.xxx%** accuracy on keras validating/testing result.

And when I imported the h5 file to test the prediction of an image, I did:

```
def grayscale(img):
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  return img

def equalize(img):
  img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
  return img

def preprocessing(img):
  gray = grayscale(img)
  eq = equalize(gray)
  return eq / 255

image = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
print("Loading model...")
model = load_model("model.h5")
classes = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', header=0, usecols=['BananaOrNot']).values

image = preprocessing(image)
image = image.reshape(100, 100, 1)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
y_prob = model.predict(image)
class_idx = y_prob.argmax(axis=-1)[0]
print(classes[class_idx][0]) # it produced wrong result (should be 'not banana', got 'banana')
```

I tested with a sample **blank white** image, and the prediction gave me **Banana** result, even though it should be **Not banana** for sure. How could it be wrong in this very simple test case? Or is there anything wrong with my `model.predict(img)` input image?

Comment: This would only work if your training set had a similar image with the label of Not Banana, else the new image is just too different from the training set.

Comment: @matias-valdenegro Oh I see. So it means my test case image is more similar to the training set with the label `Banana` compared to `Not banana`?

Comment: No, it means the model was never trained with an image like that, its not about similarity

Comment: Oh. But, because of the model was never trained with that image so the predict function will produce a random output?

Comment: @JustinusHermawan `argmax` on class probability (Model predictions) will always give you the class with highest probability/confidence (it can be 0.5 or 1.0) among the classes. You might want to check the confidence/probability value which might not be too high in these cases and based on that probability you may apply some threshold.

Comment: @bit01 I have tested with `model.predict_classes(...)` too and still got the same result.

Comment: What i mean is: if you enumerate over `y_prob` and find the maximum probability along with class index then you have an option to ignore the prediction when the probability is less than some threshold. `(class_prob,class_idx) = max((v,i) for i,v in enumerate(y_prob))` After getting `class_prob` you can decide further.

Comment: @bit01 I see. But, what about if I use `model.predict_classes(...)`? It gives me the exact binary value. Unfortunately, the class index value is still wrong.

Comment: `model.predict()` gives the class probability whereas the `model.predict_classes(...)` gives probable class with best match (highest confidence). So In both case result will be indifferent.

Comment: LGTM, so what I have to do is loop over the y_prob value and eliminate the ones lower than the threshold (ignore them)?

Comment: @bit01 or skip them when the sliding window is running?

Comment: `argmax` gives the class index having best/highest match/probability only but the probability might be low which you may want to investigate further. Therefore, looping over the y_prob value you can find the highest probability along with class index followed by applying threshold on that probability to reduce false positive.

Comment: By doing `(class_prob,class_idx) = max((v,i) for i,v in enumerate(y_prob))` I got the `class_prob` value e.g `[0.0056636 0.9943364]` which is mean 0.005xxx for class 0 and 0.994xxx for class 1. The right result of the test case should be class 0, but the highest prob is class 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no class named **Not banana** in your dataset, it gives only the classes that you've trained in your network.

In order to have that behavior on your model, you should set a class *e.g: Background* on your model and train it with certain amount of *Background* labeled images. Otherwise it would give the result that most probable one in your output vector *i.e* the most probable class even if it's a blank image.

OR

You can train a classification model along with the localization and classification only occurs in localized objects and your problem may be corrected.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But I have already class named Not banana in my dataset. And sometimes it produces Not banana result on some test cases. But the accuracy is still low.

Comment: That means, you have not a blank image labeled as *Not banana*. I think it's because of your dataset. For example if you classified a human as *Not banana* you can try the accuracy of that kind of things but the blank image is kind of deceptive if you don't have that kind of images on your dataset.

Please feel free to ask if you have further questions.

Comment: Ohh I see. But, is there anything wrong with my `model.predict(...)` code? I doubt with the `reshape(...)` and `expand_dims(...)` usage.

Comment: I see no mistakes rightnow on `model.predict` and `reshape()` or `expand_dims()`. However, if you are trying to achieve a **binary** classification, I'm kinda skeptical about the `y_prob.argmax()` since `argmax` is used for multiclass classification for constructing the confusion matrix.

Comment: It's weird. I just tested to predict with some images I got from request to urls and got perfect results. But if I cropped 100x100 rect from an image and test to predict again, it gave me wrong. This skenario I used to simulate sliding window mechanism.